# Adding analyzer to existing index in elasticsearch 6.3.1

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add analyzer in existing index in elasticsearch.

**Below is the code** :-

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/existing_index_name/_mapping/_doc?pretty" -H 'Content-Type:     application/json' -d'
{
"settings":{
    "analysis":{
    "analyzer":{
    "analyzer_startswith":{
    "tokenizer":"keyword",
    "filter":["lowercase"]
     }
    }
   }      
  }
 }
'
```

**Below is the error i am getting** :-

```
 ["type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [settings : {analysis={analyzer={analyzer_startswith={tokenizer=keyword, filter=[lowercase]}}}}]"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call the [`_settings` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis) not the `_mapping` one:

```
                                                change this
                                                     |
                                                     v
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/existing_index_name/_settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "analyzer_startswith": {
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Beware, though, that you need to first close the index:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/existing_index_name/_close
```

And then after updating the settings, you need to open it again

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/existing_index_name/_open
```

Answer (score 3):

You must first close the index
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/indexname/_close"

and then change _mappings to _settings in your curl

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/indexname/_settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "analyzer_startswith": {
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

To open index
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/indexname/_open"

Comment: I think there is a typo in your first curl command.  You said, first you close the index.  I think you mean  "http://localhost:9200/indexname/_close" not  "http://localhost:9200/indexname/_open"

Comment: @Bill thnx. I have corrected it